# Zip file reading: Is there a way to find the correct size of large files > 4GB in non-Zip64 zip files?

Tags: ruby, zip, tcl, unzip

I'm building zip files on a 64-bit Ubuntu machine using this tcl code, which
does not have the Zip64 extensions (see man zip(1) for an explanation):

Here's how I build such a zip file, using ActiveTcl 8.6 (called buildzip.tcl):

```
package require zlibtcl
package require zipfile::encode

set z [zipfile::encode Z]
set i 0
set outName out.zip
set force 0
while { $i < $argc } {
    set arg [lindex $argv $i] 
    switch -glob -- $arg {
        -o {
            set i [expr {$i + 1}]
            set outName [lindex $argv $i]
        }
        -f {
            set force 1
        }
        -* {
            puts {Usage buildzip.tcl [-f: force overwrite] [-o zipfile|out.zip] file...}
            exit
        }
        default {
            $z file: $arg 0 ./arg
        }
    }
    set i [expr {$i + 1}]
}
if { [file exists $outName] == 1 && $force == 0 } {
    puts "File $outName exists, use -f to overwrite"
    exit
}
$z write $outName
$z destroy
```

Let's create 2 large files:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=0 seek=3G of=bigfile.dat
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=0 seek=5G of=bigfile2.dat
```

Let's see how big they are:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 eric eric 5,368,709,120 Mar 20 11:14 bigfile2.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 eric eric 3,221,225,472 Mar 20 11:14 bigfile.dat
```

Let's zip them up:

```
$ tclsh buildzip.tcl -f -o foo.zip bigfile{,2}.dat
```

What size does zip think they are?

```
$ unzip -l out.zip 
Archive:  out.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
3221225472  2014-03-20 11:14   bigfile.dat
1073741824  2014-03-20 11:14   bigfile2.dat
---------                     -------
4294967296                     2 files
```

However, if I unzip them, I get the original contents back:

```
$ rm bigfile*; unzip out.zip ; L bigfil*
Archive:  out.zip
  inflating: bigfile.dat             
  inflating: bigfile2.dat            
-rw-r--r-- 1 eric eric 5,368,709,120 Mar 20 11:14 bigfile2.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 eric eric 3,221,225,472 Mar 20 11:14 bigfile.dat
```

The numeral "1073741824" is better known as 0x40000000 or 1GB.
I haven't looked at the ziplib C code yet, but I'm guessing that
1GB is a sentinel for an "impossible" value, seeing how this code
dates back to the days of $1000 20MB hard disks, without taking
Moore's law into consideration.

My question: can I discover the true size of each entry, without
having to actually extract it?  And preferably in pure Ruby?
Unzip obviously has recourse to something else that has it extract
the complete file, not the first 1GB of it.

Comment: Just for fun, if the two files are 4GB of null bytes, and 4GB nulls + 1 "a", unzip reports a buffer overflow and dumps core.

Answer (score 0):

Don't even use the directory.   The size value is the actual size mod 4GB,
so it's unreliable.  Instead use the Ruby Zip::InputStream's interface,
and read something like 8MB at a time, and bail out when we've read too much.

Ah, overflow.